# Is using unique_lock for a task that can be acomplished by lock_guard slower?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

I am confused regarding the reason why `lock_guard` exists.  Is it:

1. A simpler interface than `unique_lock`?
2. Better performance than `unique_lock`?
3. Something else?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`lock_guard` can be implemented with one unit of state: a pointer or reference to the `Mutex` type it has locked.

`unique_lock` has to both hold that state, and knowing *if it is currently locked*, as a `unique_lock` can have a `Mutex` that is not locked.  This means it must have at least a `bool` of extra state.

`lock_guard` provides a *zero* overhead RAII lock/unlock wrapper around acquiring and releasing a `Mutex`.  Basically the `lock_guard` means that there is zero reason to avoid using RAII to handle locks on a `Mutex`.

`unique_lock` can only reach zero overhead if the compiler can be convinced to notice you only use it in ways that `lock_guard` could be used (ie, construct it, then destroy it, without fiddling with it).

Beyond those efficiency arguments, a programmer who sees a `lock_guard` knows that it is going to last until end of scope without having to examine the code in the scope.  A programmer who sees a `unique_lock` must examine all use of the variable to know if this is the case.

But the above is only half the reason.

The other half of the reason is because much of the threading library for C++11 was based off of `boost` libraries, which had already implemented a mostly platform independent threading library.  Boost has both `lock_guard` and `unique_lock`, with nearly identical semantics to the C++11 versions.

So when the `boost` threading library was standardized, both where carried in, and nobody eliminated them.

Answer (score 6):

You almost answer your own question here - 1) and 2) are both good reasons. [std::lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) is a simple scoped locking object. Features like a timeout on mutex acquisition add to the complexity of the mutex primitive, increasing both the time it takes to perform the operation and the probability of contention for the mutex. So why pay for what you don't need?

Whether 'try_locking' with or without timeouts is good design is another question; like thread cancellation, a broken design which C++11 does not implement.